# Calculate the total error percentage

Tags: arithmetic

Below it the table which contains Actual Count and Error Count for each ID.

```
USER_ID    |    Actual_Count    |   Error_Count
-----------+--------------------+---------------------
1345653         5                     4
534140349       5                     0
682527813       4                     0
687612723       3                     0
704318001       5                     4
```

So if you look at the above scenario, For this `1345653` ID Out of `5`, it has `4` errors, same with `704318001` ID, out of `5` it has `4` errors. And all other ID's they didn't have any errors as `Error_Count` is `Zero` for them. So in general if I need to calculate what's the total error percentage, then How I will calculate that? Is it possible to calculate the total error percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a total of 8 errors out of 22 tries, for an error percentage of about 36.4%.